# WebAPI call brings in the xml namespace that causes the deserialization to fail

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI method like so:

```
[HttpPost, Route("api/student/studentstatus")]
public UpdatedStudent StudentStatus(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    string requestData = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    GetStudentStatus scp = null;
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GetStudentStatus), new XmlRootAttribute("GetStudentStatus"));
    using (Stream stream = request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
    {
        scp = (GetStudentStatus)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

This is the string in requestData

```
<GetStudentStatus xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/StudentStatusConsole">
<StudentID></StudentID><Batch></Batch>
</GetStudentStatus>
```

When StudentStatus is hit it dies at the Deserialize part with this error:

```
"<GetStudentStatus xmlns='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/StudentStatusConsole'> was not expected."}
```

This is the GetStudentStatus class:

```
public class GetStudentStatus
{
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Batch { get; set; }
}
```

Tried annotating the class with DataContract(NameSpace="") and adding DataMember attributes to the properties.
No go.

This is the method which calls the WebAPI:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    GetStudentStatus studentToPost = new GetStudentStatus() { StudentID = "", Batch = "" };
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:53247/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsXmlAsync("api/student/studentstatus", studentToPost);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try annotating your GetStudentStatus class with the DataContract attribute but specify the Namespace property so that it includes the namespace where the class is located.

```
[DataContract(Name = "GetStudentStatus", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/[NameSpace]")]
public class GetStudentStatus
{
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Batch { get; set; }
}
```